After click sigin button is showing: security certificate&code will handle. Chrome is blank in headless, working in headed mode in serenity framework
Serenity framework
example: customer will click on SignIn button then one security certificate will come like your connection is not private. If certificate is visible code will handle that by clcking on advanced button next continue button
when we are running script in headless mode after sign in button screen is blank.(should display either certificate page or SignIn page)
Note: when chrome is opening in (headed mode) everything is working user able to login as well.

tried with waits
took the screenshot at every step, after signIn button page is blank, it should something
I am getting the currentUrl but no title.
close the browser opened the new browser still same blank page

